# Remix - Parser Error on pragma 8.11

Tags: solidity, remix

I am using the newest version of pragma. 8.11 creating a contract for a token. I am getting a parser error at the bottom line stating expected pragma import directive. Can anyone help I feel like i have tried everything.

[image: COntract where error is occurring]

Comment: Hi BrandonH! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please include the contract code, likely you typed something wrong.

Comment: "function" before "receive()"?